# Accept Android SDK Build-Tools on Windows 10

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to understand why there is no GUI way or Post-Installation process to accept the android SDK Build Tools license:

```
Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
   build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
```

After searching a lot I found the command for sdkmanager.exe but the directory tools/bin/ does not exist in `C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`.

Can anyone help me to accept the license to move on? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view and accept all licenses of the Android SDK and related components using the following command:

```
android-sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\sdkmanager.bat --licenses
```